# Minimal polynomial in primary decomposition theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, minimal-polynomials

I am going over the proof of the primary decomposition theorem. I can prove that if we have an annihilating polynomial $f$ for some linear transformation $T:V \to V$ and $f$ can be expressed $f = ab$ with $hcf(a,b) = 1$ then we have that $V = ker(a(T)) \bigoplus ker(b(T))$.

Now I am trying to prove that if $f$ is in fact the minimal polynomial, $m_t$ then the restriction of $m_T$ to $ker(a(T))$ is given by $a$ and likewise the restriction to $ker(b(T))$ should be given by $b$. However I am struggling to prove this, seemingly obvious, fact.

Help is very much appreciated,

Thanks

Comment: Can you prove that the annihilator of a direct sum is the least common multiple of the annihilators of the direct summands?

Comment: Do you mean the least degree annihilator? And I think this is exactly what I am struggling with, thanks!

Comment: Yeah, I'm implicitly referring to the monic generator of the ideal of $F[x]$ that equals the annihilator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We show that $a(x)$ is the minimal polynomial of $T\restriction \ker(a(T))$. Let $g(x)$ be such that $g(T)$ is zero on $\ker a(T)$.
Consider $b(x)g(x)$, let $v$ be an arbitrary vector, then by what you have already shown,
$v=\alpha+\beta$ with $\alpha \in \ker  a(T)$ and $\beta \in \ker b(T)$

So now $$b(T)g(T)v=b(T)g(T)\alpha+b(T)g(T) \beta =0$$
 therefore $b(x)g(x)$ annihilates the entire space and so $f|bg$ but $f=ab$ so $a|g$, therfore $a(x)$ is the minimal polynomial of $T\restriction \ker(a(T))$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How can we deduce that since $b(x)g(x) annihilates the entire space then $f$ divides $bg$?

Comment: $f$ is assumed to be the minimal polynomial, isnt it ?

Comment: Yes, it is, I read the question again, if $g$ any annihilator the the minimum poly divides it, because otherwise use Euclidean, $g=fq+r$ and if $r\neq 0$ it is a smaller minimun polynomial.

Comment: Ah, yes of course, sorry! I was thinking $f$ was any old annihilating polynomial, but yes I forgot I am now considering the case where $f$ is the minimal polynomial! (It's been a long day) Your answer makes perfect sense to me now, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It is clear by definition that a polynomial $P$ always annihilates the restriction of $T$ to $\ker(P[T])$. So to prove that $a$ is the minimal polynomial of the restriction of $T$ to $\ker(a[T])$, the only question that remains is why no lower degree monic polynomial$~a'$ can annihilate that restriction. But then $a'b$ would annihilate the restrictions of $T$ to both ($T$-stable) summands of your direct sum decomposition, while its degree is less than that of the minimal polynomial $ab$, which contradicts the definition of the latter.